# How do the static pages of getbootstrap.com generated

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github-pages, static-pages

I try to write one static pages and upload them into github.

I noticed bootstrap also is in github.

my question is:
are there any tools to help to generate static pages? 
Can you share me the way for bootstrap?

Thanks,

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking, perhaps try wording your question a bit more succinctly.

Comment: My question is : how is the web site getbootstrap.com generated?
Can we use some tools to help to generate the pages? there are too many pages, it is very boring to write these pages one by one.

Comment: It is generated with [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), a static site generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getbootstrap.com is a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) site, which is powered by [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

Every repository on GitHub is eligible for a GitHub Pages site (defaults to http://username.github.com/projectname, but can use custom URLs with a CNAME record in the repository root). The static pages for your GH Pages site must live in a branch called `gh-pages`, which is an orphan branch so it can live parallel to the actual project's code.

For more on setting up a GitHub Pages site, see [the official docs](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/).

Comment: I found this project : https://github.com/itech001/static-site-starter .  how is it used to generate static pages? It is can be integrated with JekyII?